# Preload a large area of google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to preload areas of google maps? It takes too long on a 3G connection to load areas when travelling as speed, so would it be possible to preload an area first? If so how?

Comment: As far as I know you can't with the JS API, the closest thing I've seen is in the native mobile app where you can [cache an area of the map for later](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/2650377)

Comment: Maybe there is a way to trick it into loading an area, although I wouldn't know how you would go about caching it?

Comment: Maybe you could put the map in a really large container that overflows the size of your screen, that way it would be fetching parts you can't see sooner. But it would probably behave very strangely and there's no guarantee it would work. Personally I don't think its worth the hassle but good luck. A good motto ... _'keep it simple stupid'_

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the map tiles but I think it against there rules. Google maps uses a Morton curve to subdivide the map.